# Oracle.DataAccess issue with WcfTestClient

Tags: wcf, oracle, wcftestclient

I am running Visual Studio 2010 on a Win 7 - 64 bit machine. I created a WCF service project. I debugged it, and the WCF Test Client loaded, as expected. I ran the GetData operation, and upon doing so get this

```
Assembly Oracle.DataAccess was not found. Reinstall the assembly or Visual Studio
```

I never installed the Oracle adapter for dot net. So I search through the various machine.config files (both 32 and 64 bit versions of the framework, and multiple versions of the framework), and sure enough, there are entries for the Oracle data adapter. I removed them all, but am still getting the error.

Ideas???

Comment: I tried targeting 32-bit and 64-bit cpus in my WCF project, but that didn't work. And even if it did, that is not really a solution.

Comment: So I looked in the GAC, and saw that there were OracleClient assemblies in there. I tried uninstalling them using gacutil, but that failed due to a dependency of the .Net redist setup

Comment: Hey Kevin, did you ever resolve this? Same boat here.